# CompletableFuture supplyAsync(supplier) vs supplyAsync(supplier, executor)

Tags: java, multithreading, completable-future

Java Docs says `CompletableFuture:supplyAsync(Supplier<U> supplier)` runs the task in the `ForkJoinPool#commonPool()` whereas the `CompletableFuture:suppleAsync(supplier, executor)` runs it in the given executor.

I'm trying to figure out which one to use. So my questions are:

1. What is the `ForkJoinPool#commonPool()`?
2. When should I use  `supplyAsync(supplier)` vs `supplyAsync(supplier, executor)`?

Comment: you can use commonPool for computational work, the thread number of commonPool equals to your CPU cores. Sometimes you are going to use multi-threading for IO works such as network you may use a larger pool. Also sometimes you may want a single thread pool.

Comment: @zhh But when would you pick common pool vs Executor and vice versa?

Comment: I think the main difference is paralism. If you set the paralism of your Executor to the number of cores in cpu, there is not much difference between them(Of course there are many other parameters). For example, for matrix multiplication, I may use a commonPool or an executor with the same paralism.

Comment: If you are writing a web server and to handle network requests, you should use an executor with a large paralism.

Comment: A general rule of thumb is "never use the common pool for tasks that block on external resources". The common pool is sized to match the number of available CPUs with the assumption that there's no point in running more tasks than the available resource (CPU) can handle. You break this assumption if your tasks do nothing while they wait for something outside the box to complete.

Answer (score 5):

`ForkJoinPool#commonPool()` is the common pool of threads that Java API provides. If you ever used [stream API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html), then the parallel operations are also done in this thread pool.

The advantage of using the common thread pool is that Java API would manage that for you - from creation to destruction. The disadvantage is that you would expect a lot of classes to share the usage of this pool.

If you used an executor, then it is like owning a private pool, so nothing is going to fight with you over the usage. You make to create the executor yourself, and pass it into `CompletableFuture`. However, do note that, eventually the actual performance would still depend on what is being done in the threads, and by your hardware.

Generally, I find it fine to use the common thread pool for doing more computationally intensive stuff, while executor would be better for doing things that would have to wait for things (like IO). When you "sleep" in common thread pool thread, it is like using a cubicle in a public washroom to play games on your mobile phone - someone else could be waiting for the cubicle.

Comment: Great explanation. Could you elaborate on your last paragraph though? Especially how common thread pool would be better for doing more computationally intensive stuff than executor? And why is executor better for things like IO?

Comment: @Glide When you make your own executor, that is personal to you. On the other hand, the common pool is available for all to use - whenever you use them and let the thread sleep, you are depriving others the chance to use it. When you do pure computational operations with common pool, you are saving yourself the trouble to create your own executor/threads, since both methods still translate to actual CPU usage.

Comment: Also, when performing I/O operations, you usually use a thread pool allowing more threads than CPU cores, as blocked threads do not consume CPU cores. By the way, there are more executor types besides thread pools. One executor we use often in a desktop application is [`EventQueue::invokeLater`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/EventQueue.html#invokeLater-java.lang.Runnable-) which allows nicely combining background tasks with UI updates and queries with `CompletableFuture`…

Comment: @Holger Makes sense but just curious, how is `EvetQueue` an `Executor` when it does not extend from `java.util.concurrent.Executor`?

Comment: @Glide `Executor` is a *functional interface* with the functional signature `(Runnable) → void`, so a *method reference* to a method accepting a `Runnable` like `EventQueue::invokeLater` is valid; it’s not passing the event queue, but a method reference to the `static` method `invokeLater` which has a compatible signature.